# SQL transaction always caught

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, transactions, rollback

I have 3 `delete` queries executed by my sql command. The last of the three queries can only execute if there is no reference to it in other tables. It fails to execute if there is a reference. So, if the last delete fails, I want to `rollback` to not lose the data that would be deleted in the previous 2 commands. This is why I need to use a `SqlTransaction`.

The following is what I was able to come up with. It in fact prevents the loss of any data, however, I am unable to delete anything and am always getting the popup (meaning every time it is executed, it is caught).

```
protected void editDelete(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection();
    MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    MyConnection.Open();

    // Start a local transaction.
    SqlTransaction sqlTran = MyConnection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
        MyCommand.CommandText = /* 3 queries removed to shorten code */;
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@id", this.accountidEdit.Value);
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);

        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnection.Close();


        /* reload and notification calls removed to shorten code */
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        sqlTran.Rollback();
        X.Msg.Alert("Error", "Error.").Show();
    }

}
```

In addition, I tried to find the problem by using:

```
catch (Exception sqlexception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sqlexception.Message);
        sqlTran.Rollback();
        X.Msg.Alert("Error", "Error.").Show();
    }
```

but nothing ever wrote to the console.. weird?

Is this the proper way to execute a `SqlTransaction`? I followed [a guide from the microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this. Why is it always being caught?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to commit the SqlTransaction before you close the connection in the happy `try` block. The exception (or InnerException) should mention this.

Comment: Additionally I think you need to set the `SqlCommand.Transaction` to `sqlTran`.

Comment: @StuartLC Great observation! I did not commit. However, placing `sqlTran.Commit();` on the line directly after `MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` does not fix the issue

Comment: @juharr yes! That was the missing piece of the puzzle! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to commit the transaction `sqlTran.Commit();`.

Also, set `MyCommand.Transaction = sqlTran;` as @juharr pointed out

Comment: Great observation! I did not commit. However, placing `sqlTran.Commit();` on the line directly after `MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` does not fix the issue

Comment: The remaining issue, as @juharr pointed out, was that I also need to set `MyCommand.Transaction = sqlTran;`

Answer (score 1):

The problems are a missing transaction commit and setting the transaction for the command. Here's how I would do it with `using` statements for the connect, transaction and command that will make sure the transaction is rolled back and the connection is closed in the case of an exception without having to explicitly call `Rollback` or `Close`.  The `Commit` has to be called after executing the command.  By creating the command from the connection you don't have to set the connection, but I think you still have to set the transaction.  This can be even further simlified if you don't need the try-catch that shows the pop-up box.

```
protected void editDelete(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    using (
        var MyConnection =
            new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        MyConnection.Open();

        // Start a local transaction.
        using (var sqlTran = MyConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                using(var MyCommand = MyConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    MyCommand.CommandText = /* 3 queries removed to shorten code */;
                    MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    MyCommand.Transaction = sqlTran;
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@id", this.accountidEdit.Value);
                    MyCommand.Parameters.Add(p1);

                    MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlTran.Commit();
                }


                /* reload and notification calls removed to shorten code */
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                X.Msg.Alert("Error", "Error.").Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```